# Mvc3 implement custom action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have .net mvc3 web site. And i must to implement top menu. Each of the menu tags is lead to his action and display another view.This what i have now:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Products", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Pricing", "Pricing", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Our Team", "OurTeam", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home")</li>
</ul><!-- /menu -->
```

This view is `Html.RenderAction("Header", "Home");` in my layout(because it must to appear in all pages)
I need to implement Custom ActionLink. The anchor text must be:

```
<span>text</span><b>text</b>
```

The "text" is Home(for example of first li)
And the current ActionLink must add class :"Selected" to the anchor.

How i can do this? Help please

p.s
I can add this menu for each view in my website with "selected" class of current view, but this is not good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you want to put the "selected" class to the current displaying action.
You can do a check in the view by looking at this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

Then you put the "selected" class to your actionlink the way showed in the previous answer

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = ":selected"})</li>
```

Personally I will create a ViewModel containing a list of "MenuAction" that expose, other than the route values, a bool property "Selected". Imo from the view will be much more cleaner the handling of the data.

Comment: This is good solution. But my menu is a partial view and called from layout. so HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() will always return name of this partial, and this name will never match current action name..

Comment: Call something like that @Html.Action("MainMenu", "Menu"). than you do the logic and prepare the view in the controller

Comment: My mistake i used var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") instead of HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(). It's work now. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how i can customize anchor html : <span>text</span><b>text</b> ?

Comment: You can write your own html extension. public static MvcHtmlString MySpan(this HtmlHelper html, string myText)

Comment: if (action == currentAction && controller == currentController){var linkHtml = new StringBuilder();linkHtml.Append("<span>" + linkText + "</span>");linkHtml.Append("<b>" + linkText + "</b>");var anchor = new TagBuilder("a")anchor.Attributes["href"] = "?";How to generate anchor href in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class` with this `ActionLink` overload:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = ":selected"})</li>
```

The 5th parameter is HTML attributes.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) ActionLink of this overload

---

Update:

```
$(function(){
    var controllerName ='ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]';
    $('#' +controllerName).addClass(':selected');
});
```

Comment: You add static "selected" class to Home link. I need to add "selected" dynamically to current ActionLink

Comment: @user1086344. When do you want to add it?

Comment: When you click on "Products" for example, the page will load "products" view and "selected" class must be added to "products" anchor and removed from previous anchor.

Comment: @user1086344. I would give each `<a>` an `id` and give it `:selected` with `jquery`: `$('#Product').addClass(':selected');` you can add a script that takes the controller and give `:selected` to the `<a>` with id that match the controller name.

Comment: @user1086344. What's the problem with the server side?